# Convergence or divergence of $\sum\ln\left(n \sin \frac 1n\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln\left(n  \sin \frac 1n\right)$$
converge or diverge?

I compared this series with $\ln(n)$ which shows us that the series diverges. Nevertheless,  I noticed that the series is not positive, which does not allow us to use this test. Is my reasoning right?

Comment: By Taylor approximations, $$
\ln \left( {n\sin \frac{1}{n}} \right) \sim \ln \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{6n^2 }}} \right) \sim  - \frac{1}{{6n^2 }}
$$ as $n\to+\infty$. Use the limit comparison test to conclude.

Comment: @Gary I know that $nsin(1/n)$ approximates to the value you got inside the logarithm. But how do you establish that the logarithm approximates to $-1/(6n^2)$?

Comment: $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the series
$$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\csc\frac{1}{n}}{n}\right)$$
Ill leave it to you to show that the function in the summand is monotone decreasing. Im going to use the integral test, that is, the series converges if the following integral converges.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\csc\frac{1}{x}}{x}\right) \ dx$$
Using the substitution $x \to 1/x$, we turn the integral into something nicer,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(x\csc x\right)}{x^{2}} \ dx$$
And you can show $x^{2}$ is an upper bound for $\ln(x\csc x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$. I want to note that these functions are continuous if you define them in the right place, as in, they do not blow up, so i will not really pay attention to those places that much. And so,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(x\csc x\right)}{x^{2}} \ dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}} \ dx = 1$$
Hence, $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)$ must converge, and it follows $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)$ converges too.